# An error occurred while running subprocess npm

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

Hice una nueva aplicación de tipo sidemenu en Ionic, sin modificar nada, ejecuté el siguiente comando para hacer la compilación de Android.

• ng build

• ionic capacitor add android

Entonces, eso genera el siguiente error.

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testQR\LotoVirtual> ionic capacitor add Android --verbose
  ionic:lib Terminal info: { ci: false, shell: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', tty: true, windows: true } +0ms
  ionic:lib CLI global options: { _: [ 'capacitor', 'add', 'Android' ], help: null, h: null, verbose: true, quiet: null, interactive: true, color: true, confirm: null, json: null, project: null, '--': [] } +3ms
  ionic:lib:project Project type from config: @ionic/angular (angular) +0ms
  ionic:lib:project Project details: { context: 'app', type: 'angular', errors: [], configPath: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\testQR\\LotoVirtual\\ionic.config.json' } +0ms
  ionic Context: { binPath: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@ionic\\cli\\bin\\ionic', libPath: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@ionic\\cli', execPath: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\testQR\\LotoVirtual', version: '6.18.1' } +0ms
  ionic:lib:telemetry Sending telemetry for command: 'ionic capacitor add' [ 'Android', '--verbose', '--interactive', '--color' ] +0ms
  ionic:lib:integrations:capacitor Getting config with Capacitor CLI: [ 'config', '--json' ] +0ms
> npm.cmd i -E @capacitor/Android@latest
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@capacitor%2fAndroid - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@capacitor/Android@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-07T17_26_46_419Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm.cmd i -E @capacitor/Android@latest exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 1 functions +0ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 10356: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 10356 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: no se encontr� el proceso "10356".
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 10356 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +60ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 10356 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: no se encontr� el proceso "10356".
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 10356 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +2ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +1ms
```

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Busqué la solución, pero no puedo resolver eso

Desinstalé npm, Ionic y Capacitor, y luego los instalé nuevamente y el problema sigue

Answer (score 0):

Es curioso lo que paso, iba a hacer una prueba con el comando **ionic capacitor add android** para ver si un cambio que hice me daba resultados, sin embargo, por un "Dedazo" presione **Enter** sin terminar de poner la linia de comando y ejecute esta linia  **ionic capacitor add**, a lo que Ionic me consulto si quería realizar el proceso para Android o IOS, seleccione Android y todo funciono bien.

**En conclusión:** mi solución fue ejecutar el comando sin mucha especificación, por ejemplo:

- ionic capacitor add Android => ionic capacitor add
- ionic capacitor copy Android => ionic capacitor copy
- ionic capacitor sync Android => ionic capacitor sync